# test class for Rfleet_PaymentConditions

Tags: apex, unit-test

I have create a apex class(Rfleet_PaymentConditions) and when i am  writing a test class,i got only 29%.how to achieve 75% code coverage?
apex class:

```
public class Rfleet_PaymentConditions 
{

public Boolean bool {get;set;}
public Boolean showSave{get;set;}
public Boolean showSubmit{get;set;}
public Boolean showback{get;set;}
public string id;
public Account acc{get;set;}

public Account getAccount() {
return acc;
}

public Rfleet_PaymentConditions(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
bool = true;
showSave = true;
id=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
acc=[SELECT Rfleet_DueDate_Period1__c, Rfleet_DueDate_Period2__c, Rfleet_DueMonth_Period1__c,
Rfleet_DueMonth_Period2__c,Rfleet_LowerDate_Period1__c,Rfleet_LowerDate_Period2__c,
Rfleet_LowerMonth_Period1__c,Rfleet_LowerMonth_Period2__c,Rfleet_UpperDate_Period1__c,
Rfleet_UpperDate_Period2__c,Rfleet_UpperMonth_Period1__c,Rfleet_UpperMonth_Period2__c
FROM Account where id=:id];

}

public void save() {

bool =false;
showSave=false;
showSubmit=true;
showback=true;

 }
 public PageReference back() {

PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/' + ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')+'?inline=1');
return pageRef;

} 


public PageReference Submit() {
if(((acc.Rfleet_UpperDate_Period1__c !=acc.Rfleet_UpperDate_Period2__c)||(acc.Rfleet_UpperMonth_Period1__c !=acc.Rfleet_UpperMonth_Period2__c)) &&((acc.Rfleet_LowerDate_Period1__c != acc.Rfleet_LowerDate_Period2__c)||(acc.Rfleet_LowerMonth_Period1__c!=acc.Rfleet_LowerMonth_Period2__c))){
update acc;
}else{

ApexPages.Message msg = new Apexpages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Warning,'Period1 overlaping to Period2!');
  ApexPages.addmessage(msg);
}
//PageReference pr= new PageReference('/'+acc.id+'?inline=0');
//System.Debug('-------------> the value of acc is' + acc);

//return pr;
return null;
       }
```

}
    =====================================

```
test class:
@isTest
public class Rfleet_PaymentConditions_test {
static testMethod void TestvalidateDate() {

    Account test = new Account(Name='sample demo',Rfleet_DueDate_Period1__c = '4',Hello__c='sdf', Number_Of_Locations__c=5.67, Sales_Rep__c='samplled');
    insert test;
    test.Rfleet_DueDate_Period1__c='5';

    update test;
   Account myTestTrainee = [SELECT id From Account LIMIT 1];
    PageReference myVfPage = Page.payment;
   system.test.setCurrentPage(myVfPage);
   // test.setCurrentPage(myVfPage); 
   // ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id', account.id);//Pass Id to page
    ApexPAges.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(myTestTrainee);
      Rfleet_PaymentConditions apextestclass=new Rfleet_PaymentConditions(sc);
         apextestclass.save();
        apextestclass.back();
        apextestclass.Submit();
     }}
```

Comment: Use the [Developer Console](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=code_dev_console_tests_coverage.htm&language=en_US) to identify the lines that are not covered and add code to the test that touches those parts.

Answer (score 0):

Pl try to uncomment the given line and use test.Id instead of account.id
ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id', test.id);//Pass Id to page

Comment: yes,its working fine

Comment: hi,saam its working fine